# Specify Java Location for Gatling

Tags: java, gatling

I am running Gatling on Centos server. The Server has Java 1.7 installed which is not supported by Gatling 2.2 and I am not allowed to update Java version. I was wondering if there was a way to specify java location in gatling configuration to run from a specific Java installation and not from /usr/bin or /usr/sbin. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `gatling.sh` script to launch Gatling, you can just edit that script to refer to whatever installation of the JDK that you want. You can set a local `JAVA_HOME` value and also prefix the calls to `java` executable with the full path of your JDK 8 installation.

For example, near the end of the shell script, something like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/JDK8

# Run the compiler
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java java $COMPILER_OPTS -cp "$COMPILER_CLASSPATH" io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler -ccp "$COMPILATION_CLASSPATH" "$@"  2> /dev/null

# Run Gatling
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$GATLING_CLASSPATH" io.gatling.app.Gatling "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you E-Riz :)

Answer (score 2):

You could `export JAVA_HOME=/<your-path>` before running gatling.

Comment: That will change the java location for all applications, no?

Comment: Should just be for your current shell session

Comment: Thank you Mr, Bob Brinks :)